# executing script as sudo -u user with php, while stopping apache script get killed also

Tags: php, apache, kill, sudo

In my php script I use line like that to execute some script:

```
exec('sudo -u USERNAME ./script.sh', $result)
```

The script is executed correctly by user USERNAME but if I stop apache or it get crashed the script also get killed. How to execute that script as user USERNAME and turn off apache without killing the script?

Comment: why would you be turning appache off?

Comment: Especially to test something but I am more afraid of crash.